# Android, Bluestacks: "open failed: EISDIR (Is a directory)"

Tags: java, android, bluestacks

I'm getting `open failed: EISDIR (Is a directory)`. All the solutions I've found from that say to call `file.getParentFile().mkdirs()`, but I'm still getting that error. It prints out `Good` but also prints out `Directory not created`.

```
    String state = Environment.getExternalStorageState();
    if (Environment.MEDIA_MOUNTED.equals(state))
    {
        Log.e("test", "Good");
    }

    File f = Environment.getExternalStorageDirectory();
    lvlWriter.writeLevel(f);
```

.

```
writeLevel(File f)
{
        File file = new File(f, "1.txt");

        if (!file.getParentFile().mkdirs())
        {
            Log.e("test", "Directory not created");
        }

        if (!file.exists())
        {
            file.createNewFile();
        }
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Okay, I found the answer. I was probably trying to write to a folder that doesn't exist in Bluestacks. This is what does work:

```
String base = Environment.getExternalStorageDirectory().getAbsolutePath() + "/bstfolder/BstSharedFolder/";
```

And that folder can then be accessed in Windows from `C:\ProgramData\BlueStacks\UserData\SharedFolder`